# Where can I check CAN frame errors in CANalyzer?

Tags: embedded, can-bus, canalyzer

Where can I check the CAN frame related errors in CANalyzer (form error,bit error,stuff error,ack error,crc error)?

Answer (score 1):

If there are any errors in the CAN frames, it appears in the Trace window along with the time-stamp at which the error occurred. Apart from this, the Bus Statistics window also shows how many error frames were generated.